# QThreads never quit although emit Finished reached

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

**Following scenario:**

If the user press the "StartMeasure" button I start a new worker thread to avoid blocking behaviour in GUI!

There I start again n new threads for hardware communication (need parallel flow for reasons of speed) -> send/receive something and evaluate the response.

**Thread model:**

[image]

The problem is that the n worker threads (for HW communication) never quits!

**Simplified code:**

```
void Tool::on_btn_StartMeasure()
{
    TestExecution *testExecution = new TestExecution();
    QThread *workerThread = new QThread();

    connect(workerThread, &QThread::started, testExecution, &TestExecution::DoTest);
    connect(testExecution, &TestExecution::Finished, workerThread, &QThread::quit);

    testExecution->moveToThread(workerThread);
    workerThread->start();
}
```

**TestExecution Class**

```
class TestExecution : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        void DoTest();

    signals:
         void Finished();

};

void TestExecution::DoTest()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TestFlow>> objects;
    std::vector<QThreads*> workerThreads;        

    for(int n=0; n<numberOfDevices; n++)
    {
        workerThreads.push_back(new QThread());
        objects.push_back(std::make_shared<TestFlow>());
        connect(workerThreads.back(), &QThread::started, objects.back().get(), &TestFlow::DoWork);
        connect(objects.back().get(), &TestFlow::Finished, workerThreads.back(), &QThread::quit);

        objects.back()->moveToThread(workerThreads.back());
        workerThreads.back()->start;
    }    

    // wait for worker threads to finish
    for(auto it=workerThreads.begin(); it!=workerThreads.end(); it++)
    {
        (*it)->wait(30); // wait a maximum of 30s -> for testing
    }

    // do something with the result <--- NEVER REACHED

    emit Finished();
}
```

**TestFlow Class**

```
class TestFlow : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        void DoWork();

    signals:
         void Finished();

};

void TestFlow::DoWork()
{
    // do something
    emit Finished(); <-- REACHED
}
```

If I reach the Finished signal in TestFlow he steps into `qobject_impl.h` to the method `QSlotObjectBase::call(Object *r, void **a)` and stops there. If I wait long enough (thread timeout of 30s) the workerThreads terminates!

Something wrong or missing here?

Thank you for any help!

**UPDATE:**

output of qDebug (only 1 worker thread)

```
Tool::on_btn_StartMeasure(), currentThread QThread(0x601b08), object thread QThread(0x601b08)
TestExecution::DoTest(), currentThread QThread(0x388bf68) , object thread QThread(0x388bf68)
TestFlow::DoWork(), currentThread QThread(0x3958690) , object thread QThread(0x3958690)
```

Looks ok to me?!

Comment: You connect signals and slots before you move your objects to other threads. The `Qt::AutoConnect` is used in `connect()` and both objects are in the same thread at that moment. I'm not sure if it automatically changes the connection's properties when you move the target object to other thread. I guess, it wants to invoke the slot in the thread where you created and connected the objects but that thread is sleeping on `wait()`.

Comment: Btw., it is useful to inspect the threads, e.g. put `qDebug()<<"DoWork/DoTest/on_btn_StartMeasure, current thread "<<QThread::currentThread()<<", object thread "<<thread()` in `DoWork()` and `DoTest()` and `on_btn_StartMeasure()`, and you'll see what threads the objects belong to and where the methods are running.

Comment: @EvgenyS. Output of qDebug: Tool::on_btn_StartMeasure, currentThread QThread(0x601b08), object thread QThread(0x601b08) | TestExecution::DoTest(), currentThread QThread(0x388bf68) , object thread QThread(0x388bf68) | TestFlow::DoWork(), currentThread QThread(0x3958690) , object thread QThread(0x3958690)   It looks ok for me?!

Comment: @EvgenyS. I also changed the order of connect my signals! Same issue!

Comment: Ok, looks strange. Why don't you try to call `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(thread(),"quit",Qt::QueuedConnection)` directly in the `DoWork()` instead of `emit Finished();`? Will it help?

Comment: @EvgenyS. This works! Thank you. Is this a Qt bug?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug. In general, object's slots are invoked in the thread where the object `lives`. Note, that `QThread` object manages some thread but as an `QObject` itself it lives in the thread it was created in. So, its slots called with `Qt::QueuedConnection` are invoked in that thread but not in the thread this `QThread` manages. I guess, in your case you block that object's thread with `wait()`, so the thread where `quit()` is expected to be invoked is frozen with that `wait()` calls and nothing can be executed there.

Comment: According to this explanation, I expect that if you put something long running in `TestFlow::DoWork()` then my previous advice will not work in some cases. Actually, for your case, when you want to run a number of concurrent works in parallel threads and then collect results of their completion, there is a better technique in Qt than direct use of `QThread`. You can use `QtConcurrent::run()` to run threads in a pool of threads and `QFuture` to wait for results.